# Many-to-Many update controller in Entity Framework 6 and Web API

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I can't get an Update controller in Web API to update both the object called and the referenced objects during the same call.

I have two classes:

```
public class Foo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(250)]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    ...
    public virtual ICollection<Bar> Bars { get; set; }
}

public class Bar
{
     public int Id { get; set }
     public string Name { get; set; }
     ...
     public virtual ICollection<Foo> Foos { get; set; }
}
```

and a controller

```
public class BarController : ApiController
{
    private DbContext db = new DbContext();

    [HttpGet]
    public IQueryable<Bar> getBar(int id)
    {
         Bar bar = await db.Bars.FindAsync(id);
         if(bar == null)
         {
             return NotFound();
         }
         return OK(bar);
    }

    [ResponseType(typeof(Bar))]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostBar(Bar bar)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
             return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        db.Bar.Add(bar);
        foreach(var foo in bar.Foos)
        {
            db.Foos.Attach(foo);
        }
        await db.SaveChangesAsync();

        return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = bar.Id }, bar);
    }

    [ResponseType(typeof(void))]
    public async Task(IHttpActionResult) PutBar(int id, Bar bar)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
             return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        if (id != ticket.Id)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }

        db.Entry(bar).State = EntityState.Modified;

        await db.SaveChangesAsync();

        return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
    }
    ...
}
```

Entity Framework creates a linking table correctly called FooBar (in this example), with the foreign Key relationships to Foo and Bar respectively.

A 'get' call resolves the reference, and returns an array of 'foos' with the rest of the bar object.

A 'post' call also resolves correctly, although without the `foreach` section, it would create new foo objects before linking.

However, a 'put' call only updates the Bar object, but does not update the linking to the Foo objects.

Updating the put controller to:

```
    [ResponseType(typeof(void))]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PutBar(int id, Bar bar)
    {
        ...

        Bar _bar = db.Bars.Find(id);
        List<Foo> addedFoos = bar.Foos.Except(_bar.Foos,
            new KeyEqualityComparer<Bar, int>(x => x.Id)).ToList();
        List<Foo> removedFoos = _bar.Foos.Except(bar.Foos,
            new KeyEqualityComparer<Bar, int>(x => x.Id)).ToList();

        removedFoos.ForEach(c => _bar.Foos.Remove(c));
        addedFoos.ForEach(c =>
        {
            if (db.Entry(c).State == EntityState.Detached)
            {
                db.Foos.Attach(c);
            }
            _bar.Foos.Add(c);
        });

        await db.SaveChangesAsync();

        return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
    }
```

would allow the update controller to update the Bar's Foo collection, but not the rest of Bar.

Unfortunately, attempting to use both calls would always throw an 'Attaching Entity of type' error, as each bar item loaded a foo item into the context, and visa versa.

Trying something akin to:

```
db.Entry(_bar).CurrentValues.SetValues(bar);
db.Entry(_bar).Collection(b => b.Foos).Load();
db.Entry(_bar).Collection(b => b.Foos).CurrentValue = bar.Foos;
```

caused an exponentially growing number of copies of both foo and bar on every update.

Is there any way around this? It strikes me odd that Entity Framework would produce the correct database structure, but make it impossible to work on.

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly, are you trying to update properties of bar as well as remove Foos from bars collection?

Comment: On an update, the collection of Foos on bar will have changed. Their may be some new associations to be linked, and some old links to be removed.

Answer (score 0):

Attempt this and let me know if you have issues

```
Bar _bar = db.Bars.Find(id);
var removed =_bar.Foos.Except(bar.Foos);
var added = bar.Foos.Except(_bar.Foos);

var toRemoveTracked =_bar.Foos.Where(foo => removed.Any(r => r.FooId == foo.FooId))
                              .ToList();

added.ToList().ForEach(_bar.Foos.Add);
toRemoveTracked.ForEach((fooo) => {_bar.Foos.Remove(fooo);});

await db.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Also remove lazy loading from your `ICollection<Foo>` property, (done by removing the virtual keyword that precedes `ICollection`)